# how to upload all of the contents in a folder from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload, directory

i'm trying to upload all of the contents in a folder to another folder in my server using jsp and servlets. I already got one FileUpload but as you may know i can only choose a single file. Is there some possible way to do this?? To be able to choose a folder instead of a single file from a jsp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to realize is that JSP is just a Java based view technology which allows you to control the output of HTML/CSS/JS using Java. After all, it's just HTML/CSS/JS which ends up in the webbrowser. In HTML, there's no possibility to select a folder for upload. The HTML `<input type="file">` simply isn't designed for that. JSP can't do much about it.

Your best bet is creating a [Java applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) utilizing [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) which is set to folder selection. You can embed it in the JSP page the usual HTML way. There are several 3rd party applets available which you could just download/buy and embed it in the JSP, but unfortunately none of them is freeware.

- [MyUploader](http://www.javaatwork.com/)
- [Rad Upload](http://radinks.com/upload/)
- [HTTP File Upload Applet](http://www.jscape.com/httpfileuploadapplet/)
- [JavaPowUpload](http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload-applet/java-uploader.aspx)
- [JFileUpload](http://www.jfileupload.com/products/jfileupload/index.html)