# Option To Choose and Upload directories in Jsp or Html

Tags: jsp

I know that there is no direct option to choose directories in html or jsp. But i just want to know if it is possible through any methods by using scripting...or any frameworks. I am asking this because in java swings this option is made possible thourgh jfilechooser. So i want also to know that if it could be embedded in browser or so...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115391/how-to-upload-all-of-the-contents-in-a-folder-from-jsp

Comment: http://sapphion.com/2011/11/html5-folder-upload-with-webkitdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing something similar, I am using the Spring Framework and it all seems easy enough to get it up and running.

I used this website to get me going.
[Spring upload tutorial](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/Spring3-MVC-Upload-File.html)

Comment: the answer which you gave is for uploading files and taking directory from file path, but i want actually an option for choosing only directories, something like which you have in swings.jfilechooser.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it. Try adding this to your `<input>`:

```
multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory=""
```

Won't work in all browsers, though.